# "Windows Live Messenger 2011 is not supported or installable on Windows XP"

Tags: windows-xp, windows-live-messenger

The latest version of Messenger (i.e. Windows Live Messenger 2011) will only install on Windows 7.

http://explore.live.com/windows-live-2011-system-requirements

Not to mention the "forced" upgrades to 2011:
http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1624009

http://www.pressbyte.com/1107/prevent-windows-live-messenger-2009-forced-update/

I've spent a couple hours on Google and there doesn't seem to be solution (other than staying with 2009 version).

Is there any way to "trick it" into installing on Windows XP?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately no, WLM2011 requires Vista+ to install.

> **Windows Live Essentials 2011 requires the following:**
>
> Operating system: 32- or 64-bit version of Windows 7, or Windows Vista with Service Pack 2 and the Platform Update for Windows Vista, or Windows Server 2008 R2, or Windows Server 2008 with Service Pack 2 and the Platform Update for Windows Server 2008.

Perhaps look into an alternative?:

- https://superuser.com/questions/83239/windows-live-messenger-replacement
- https://superuser.com/questions/80465/best-alternative-to-windows-live-messenger